# Saving IMDb posters with php

Tags: php, image, save, imdb

I'm making a script for myself to list my favorite movies. So I nearly finished it but I cannot save the small poster from IMDb with php. I used the `file_put_contents()` function, but it's creating a 0kb jpeg file. here is the code that I used:

```
file_put_contents('./posters/t0120689.jpg', file_get_contents('http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTUxMzQyNjA5MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwOTU2NTY3._V1._SX214_CR0,0,214,314_.jpg'));
```

Of course it didn't work. Then I used cURL:

```
$ch = curl_init(
file_put_contents('./posters/t0120689.jpg', file_get_contents('http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTUxMzQyNjA5MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwOTU2NTY3._V1._SX214_CR0,0,214,314_.jpg');
$fp = fopen('./posters/t0120689.jpg', 'wb');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

and it didn't work either. This is the example movie page from IMDb: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120689/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running this worked for me on my Macbook:

```
<?php
file_put_contents('./t0120689.jpg', file_get_contents('http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTUxMzQyNjA5MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwOTU2NTY3._V1._SX214_CR0,0,214,314_.jpg'));
?>
```

If you are hosting this on a server somewhere, the php ini setting `allow_url_include` needs to be set to on in order for you te get requests outside of your domain.

Comment: I am running it with my own computer. And I can get html codes of an URL with file_get_contents.

Comment: That would be my guess as well. Worked fine on my end too. +1

Comment: yeah I used it to save it to another location and it worked. But I'm scripting my site with Codeigniter and it has a .htaccess file. How can I disable rewrite rules for /posters folder?

Comment: Sounds liek a followup question. You'll have to post the contents of the .htaccess file.